# OpenMP performance degradation with parallel for loop

Tags: performance, caching, openmp, race-condition, hough-transform

I applied omp parallel for construct on following piece of code (from hough transform)

```
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i+=2){
        for(k = 0; k < limit; k++){
            theta1 = a - v + ((double) k * step);
            theta2 = b - v + ((double) k * step);
            rho1 = useful_pixels[i]*(h->trigo[(2*k) + 1]) + useful_pixels[i+1] * (h->trigo[2*k]);
            rho2 = useful_pixels[i]* (h->trigo[2*k])  - useful_pixels[i+1]*(h->trigo[(2*k) + 1]);
            hold_index[(i*limit) + (2*k)] = index(rows, cols, rho1, theta1);
            hold_index[(i*limit) + (2*k)+ 1] = index(rows, cols, rho2, theta2);


        }
    }
```

I believe there will be no race conditions, as each iteration and thread is updating different index from hold_index (integer pointer). Can someone suggest what could possibly be the bottleneck? I am getting 50% slower execution with parallel version on processing 300 video frames.

In original code, threads are being created in a function which is being called from while loop for each frame in video.
Time captured with time utility in linux.

Serial : 32,768 s
Parallel: 45,238 s

compilation: 
g++ stack.cpp -o test_code -std=c++11  -fopenmp

Adding reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double * trigo;
int *hold_index;
double thetaRadian, thetaDeg = 0;
double hTime;
int rho1,rho2;
double theta1, theta2;
vector<int> pix;
vector<int>::size_type sz;  

trigo = (double *) malloc(64 * sizeof(double) / 0.1);
for (int  i = 0; i < 640; i+= 2)
{
    thetaRadian = (thetaDeg * PI) /  180.0;
    trigo [i] = cos(thetaRadian);
    trigo [i+1] = sin(thetaRadian);
    thetaDeg += 0.1;
}
sz = 3534;

hold_index = (int *)malloc(320*sz*sizeof(int));
for(int h=0; h < 300;h++){
for(int i = 0; i < sz/2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        pix.push_back(i);
        pix.push_back(j);
                }
}
memset(hold_index,0, 320*sz*sizeof(int));
//hTime = omp_get_wtime();  
#pragma omp parallel shared (hold_index)
{
#pragma omp for private(rho1,rho2,theta1,theta2)
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i+=2){
      for(int k = 0; k < 320; k++){
    //cout << "here\n";
        theta1 = 29 + ((double) k * 0.1);
        theta2 = 119 + ((double) k * 0.1);
        rho1 = pix[i]*(trigo[(2*k) + 1]) + pix[i+1] * (trigo[2*k]);
        rho2 = pix[i]* (trigo[2*k])  - pix[i+1]*(trigo[(2*k) + 1]);
        hold_index[(i*320) + (2*k)] = 10;
        hold_index[(i*320) + (2*k)+ 1] = 20;


    }
}}
//hTime = omp_get_wtime() - hTime;



free(hold_index);
pix.clear();}
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] along with specific observations of performance and a description of the system & compile commands.

Comment: You should try the same test with optimizations enabled, perhaps `-O2`. Also, from what I can tell your `sz`is only 1250, so the two loops together iterate over some 300000 elements, which is not that much.

Comment: `time` usually prints out different numbers. Please add *all* of them to your question.

Comment: Also something is **really off** if a mere 400k iterations of this loop take 30 seconds. Even without any optimization.

Comment: This is not my actual code. In the actual code , I am processing a video with 300 frames. value of sz is 3534 for this test video.                                                  
Parallel : real 0m45,737s
              user 2m48,220s
               sys 0m0,336s                                                 
Serial :   real 0m35,413s
              user 1m6,542s
              sys 0m0,229s

Comment: You need to provide us with consistent information. You don't need to post your actual code, but your example must exhibit the actual performance issue.

Comment: With the reproducible example, it does work well, but with my actual code it doesn't. I am trying to keep reproducible example as similar as possible. only thing is opencv part is not involved here. Can openCV compiled WITH_OPENMP flag cause extra overhead too?

Comment: If you are calling OpenMP enabled openCV functions from inside the parallel region of your code, and have nested parallelism enabled you likely have huge over-subscription which is a good recipe for poor performance...